# I did't get reputation for vote-ups

Tags: support

recently I got some upvotes but no reputation for that, why is that?
I thought this would depend on an delay to refresh the reputation, but this was several days ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably talking about [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/40051#40051).

You answered a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/201409) post. There's no rep for those. (See the linked FAQ for details.)